# Add multiple world clocks in the same window?

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a script to display multiple world clocks in the same window. When I add the first clock its working fine, but when I add the second clock it just duplicates the first clock. It also doesn't tick.

When I try to change the zone it updates the first clock.

```
 <SCRIPT language="javascript">
            function addRow(tableID) {

            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

            var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

            for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;

            //alert(newcell.childNodes);
            switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
            case "text":
            newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
            break;
            case "checkbox":
            newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
            break;
            case "select-one":
            newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
            break;
            }
         }
     }

            function deleteRow(tableID) {
            try {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;

            for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
            if(rowCount <= 1) {
            alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
            break;
            }
            table.deleteRow(i);
            rowCount--;
            i--;
             }

           }
          }catch(e) {
           alert(e);
         }
      }

     </SCRIPT>


    <script language="javascript">

    var timerRunning = false;
    var timezone = "Greenwich Mean Time";  // what time zone are you in ?
    var adjust = 0;

    function timeCheck(diff) {

            if (timerRunning) {
                clearTimeout(updatetime);
                timerRunning = false; 
            }

            gmtOffset = eval(diff);

            checkDateTime();
    }

    function checkDateTime() {

            var today = new Date();
            var year = today.getYear() + 1900;
            var month = today.getMonth()+1;
            var date = today.getDate();
            var day = today.getDay();
            var hour = today.getHours();
            var minute = today.getMinutes();
            var second = today.getSeconds();

            var lastSat = date - (day+1);
            while (lastSat < 32) lastSat+=7;
            if (lastSat > 31) lastSat+=-7;
            var firstSat = date - (day+1);
            while (firstSat > 0) firstSat+=-7;
            if (firstSat < 1) firstSat+=7;
            if ((((month == 4) && (date >= firstSat)) || month > 4) &&
            (month < 11 || ((month == 10) && day <= lastSat))) adjust += 60;
            yourOffset = (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset();
            yourOffset = yourOffset + adjust;

            var xx = navigator.appName
            var xy = navigator.appVersion;
            xy = xy.substring(0,1);
            if ((xy == 4) && (xx == "Netscape")) yourOffset = yourOffset+adjust;
            if ((((month == 4) && (date > 20)) || month > 4) && (month < 11 || ((month == 10) &&
            day < 30))) adjust -= 60;

            ourDifference = eval(gmtOffset - yourOffset);
            var half = eval(ourDifference % 60);
            ourDifference = Math.round(ourDifference / 60);
            hour = eval(hour - ourDifference);
            var m = new Array("",
            "Jan","Feb","Mar",
            "Apr","May","Jun",
            "Jul","Aug","Sept",
            "Oct","Nov","Dec");
            var leap = eval(year % 4);

            if ((half == -30) || (half == 30)) minute += 30;
            if (minute > 59) minute -= 60, hour++;
            if (minute < 0) minute += 60, hour--;
            if (hour > 23) hour -= 24, date += 1;
            if (((month == 4) || (month == 6) ||
            (month == 9) || (month == 11)) && (date==31)) date = 1, month ++;
            if (((month == 2) && (date > 28)) && (leap != 0)) date = 1, month ++;
            if ((month == 2) && (date > 29)) date = 1, month++;
            if (hour < 0) hour += 24, date --;
            if ((date == 32) && (month == 12)) month = m[1], date = 1, year++;
            if (date == 32) date = 1, month++;
            if ((date < 1) && (month == 1)) month= m[12], date = 31, year--;
            if (date < 1) date = 31, month --;
            if (((month == 4) || (month == 6) ||
            (month== 9) || (month == 11)) && (date == 31)) date = 30;
            if ((month == 2) && (date > 28)) date = 29;
            if (((month == 2) && (date > 28)) && (leap != 0)) date=28;

            for (i=1; i<13; i++) {
                    if (month == i) {
                        month = m[i]; break;
                }
            }

            var dateTime = hour;
            dateTime = ((dateTime < 10) ? "0":"") + dateTime;
            dateTime = "   " + dateTime;
            dateTime += ((minute < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + minute;
            dateTime += ((second < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + second;
            dateTime += (hour >= 12) ? " PM, " : " AM, ";
            dateTime += month + " " + date + ", " + year;

            document.getElementById("zonetime").innerHTML = dateTime;

            updatetime=setTimeout("checkDateTime()", 900);
            timerRunning = true;
    }

    </script>


     <INPUT type="button" value="Add Clock" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

     <INPUT type="button" value="Delete Clock" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" /><br/><br/>


    <TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1" align="center">
            <TR>
                 <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD>
                <TD>
                    <select onchange="timeCheck(this.value)" size="0" align="center">
                        <option value="">SELECT --> COUNTRY</option>
                        <option value="+480">Pacific</option> // Australia UTC offset value is 10
                        <option value="+420">Central</option>
                        <option value="+300">Estern</option>
                        <option value="+600">Hawaii</option>
                        <option value="+360">Mexico</option>
                        <option value="-330">New Delhi</option>
                        <option value="-480">HONG KONG</option>
                        <option value="-540">TOKYO</option>
                        <option value="+0">London</option>
                    </select>
                </TD>
                <TD><div id="zonetime"></div></TD>
            </TR>
    </TABLE>
```

Comment: just a note, you might want to make your html more up-to-date... use `<script type="text/javascript">` instead of `<SCRIPT language="javascript">`, and make sure the `<TABLE>`, `<INPUT>` tags are in lowecase, etc... You also don't need to have the first two code blocks inside different `<script>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

The `gmtOffset` variable is global and your clock output cell is referenced by the same id on every row. This means that every time you change timezone the first cell with that id will be updated, i.e. the last cell on the first row.

You must ensure that the id is unique for each clock, e.g. `<td><div id="zonetime_n"</div></td>` where **n** is the row number. You'll then need to map that id to its timezone and update accordingly.